# Android apitrace failed to run

Tags: android, opengl-es

I would like to use the apitrace project on android. I followed [the instructions from the readme file](https://wiki.mozilla.org/B2G/Debugging_OpenGL).

But get no trace where created.
I run this command

```
adb shell TRACE_FILE=/data/test.trace LD_PRELOAD=/data/egltrace.so am start -n APP_NAME
```

How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1):

I tried following the instructions in *Dalvik.markdown* of the original distribution of apitrace, but without success.

The instructions say to set two properties: `wrap._process_name_` and `debug.apitrace.procname`. The former has to be set, according to those instructions, to `LD_PRELOAD=/data/egltrace.so`. When launching the application I still wouldn't get any trace generated nor any apitrace-related message in the logcat.

I had more success by putting the `LD_PRELOAD` instruction in a script and using that as the wrapper. This is the script that I use, called */data/apitrace.sh*:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/data/egltrace.so exec $@
```

You can also set the `TRACE_FILE` environment variable to specify the path to which the trace file should be written to. Otherwise it will be _/data/app_process.trace_. For example:

```
TRACE_FILE=/data/apitraces/mytrace.trace LD_PRELOAD=/data/egltrace.so exec $@
```

I believe apitrace takes care of adding numbers to the filename to prevent overwriting existing ones. So you'll have *mytrace.trace*, *mytrace.1.trace*, and so on.

So with this script in place I set the properties like so:

```
adb shell setprop wrap._process_name_ /data/apitrace.sh
adb shell setprop debug.apitrace.procname _process_name_
```

And then I launch the application. I see in the logcat something like the following:

```
I/dalvikvm( 5980): Exec: /system/bin/sh -c /data/apitrace.sh /system/bin/app_process /system/bin --application '--nice-name=_process_name_' com.android.internal.os.WrapperInit 25 17 'android.app.ActivityThread'
D/apitrace( 5991): apitrace: loaded
D/apitrace( 5991): apitrace[5991]: enabled for _process_name_
D/apitrace( 5991): apitrace: tracing to /data/app_process.trace
```

I'm using CyanogenMod 10.1.3, which is based on Android 4.2.2.